# UIScrollView detect tap

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a UIScrollView in which I need to be able to scroll. At the same time, I need to detect taps on the scrollview. How can I achieve that?

I've already tried adding a TapGestureRecognizer to the view without any luck. Also tried several approaches using the UIScrollViewDelegate methods.

There is MPMoviePlayerController view inside the UIScrollView.

I used the following code adding the reconigzer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)] autorelease];
singleTap.enabled = YES;
singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: When adding a MPMoviePlayerController's view to a UIScrollView one need to disable the userinteraction on the MpMoviePlayerController's view in order for the UIScrollView to be able to catch a gesture recognizer. This solution ofc only works when you do not want the interaction using mpmovieplayercontrollers default menus etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put a view in the scroll view and add the gesture recognizer and the other view to that.

Comment: Your response wasn't the right solution, however, it led me to it. As i was adding the mp-view inside the scrollview i had to disable userinteraction on the mpmovieplayercontroller for the scrollview to handle the gesture.

Comment: Then make your solution an answer and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture any kind of gestures in the UIScrollView. Make sure you also handle some of the default properties as well like set cancelsTouchesInView property to false, it is true by default. Also give some tag nos to your sub views to distinguish in selectors. & also enable their User interaction to true.

for eg. I am adding an image view in my scroll view, I am enabling its userinteraction as well I am also updating its content size,

```
   {
           //adding images to the scroll view   
             for i in 0 ..< 4 {
          let image = UIImage(named: "img\(i).png")
          let imageView  = UIImageView(image: image)
          imageView.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * 60 + 60/2, y: 60/2)
          imageView.tag = i
          imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          addSubview(imageView)

          let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapImage(_:)))
          imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }

        contentSize = CGSize(width: 10 * 60, height:  60 + 2*10)
```

}